# Swift 4 - DynamoDB data not showing up in TableView

Tags: swift, tableview, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to point an existing table view to the new DynamoDB database. The AWS DynamoDB call populates an array of dictionaries variable in tableview but the simulator is showing the data. I have spent several days trying with asynchronous function call with a completion closure without success. Now I got rid of the custom function and directly using the AWS closure in viewDidLoad() of table view. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the table view code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //dynamodb call
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 20

    dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Employees.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in

        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
        }

        let paginatedOutput = task.result! 

        for emp in paginatedOutput.items as! [Employees]  {

            self.myVariables.empDict["empid"] =  emp._empid
            self.myVariables.empDict["email"] = emp._email
            self.myVariables.empDict["firstname"] = emp._firstname
            self.myVariables.empDict["lastname"] = emp._lastname
            self.myVariables.empDict["location"] = emp._location
            self.myVariables.empDict["mobile"] = emp._mobile
            self.myVariables.empDict["work"] = emp._work
            self.myVariables.empDict["site"] = emp._site

            self.myVariables.arrayEmployees.append(self.myVariables.empDict)

            //print(self.myVariables.arrayEmployees) // this works

        } // for loop

        self.employeeSearch = self.myVariables.arrayEmployees
        print("printing employeeSearch")
        print(self.employeeSearch) // This works
// self.employee1View.reloadData()
// tried reloading here (above - showing here as commented), but getting error: UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only
        return nil
    } // dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan
// self.employee1View.reloadData()
// Then I tried reload above (showing here as commented), but I get error : Expected ',' separator. If I accept compiler's suggestion, it puts a comma just after curly braces above and that causes more errors at the Line dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan error : Cannot invoke 'continueWith' with an argument list of type '(block: (AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any?, Void)' 
    ) // .continueWith
// end dynamodb call

    // other things in this overload function
    // ..
    }

}
```

Then, when I run the code, I add a print command in override tableview, but it is showing a blank array like [].

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("printing employeSearch from numberOfRowsInSection")
    print(employeeSearch) // This returns blank like []
    if isSearching {
        return currentEmployeeSearch.count
    }
    return employeeSearch.count
```

}

I tried reload of table view in multiple tries, but that didn't help either.

Here is the search feature having the isSearching variable

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        employee1View.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        employeeSearch = empListDict // getSwiftArrayFromPlist()

        currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter {($0["lastname"]?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) ?? false}
        employee1View.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the isSearching variable ? do you set the variable in your code to false ? 
have u tried to reload your data in the closure where you get the data ?

Comment: I have edited my question to add isSearching portion of code. It is just to see if the user clicks on search bar or not. This has worked for the last six months when I had the data populating from an array (source of array is plist). I tried to reload the tableview inside the closure , but I get error messages

Comment: show the error messages  and can you edit your question and write where exactly you tried to reload your data

Comment: Edited my code to show the places where I added the reload code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok tried to reload your data after you get your data, for example in your Closure.

You have to reload your data in your main thread like that :

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {  
self.employee1View.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Seeing progress. I added the code as you suggested just above "return nil" inside the closure and not the table shows values. Thank you. The issue now is, when I click on search box and type a last name letter, the table view blanks out and never reloads again, even if I cancel search

Comment: can you create a new question or show more details ? have you more search functions ? and what happens exactly when you reload your data ? 
and if the answer is right click on the hook for the another user to find the solution

Comment: Found the issue and fixed it. I commented out an extra line I had written to try something. Thank you very much. I have been working on this issue for a week now. It took only minutes for you..too good. Thank you. I am learning a lot!

Comment: I just cut-pasted your solution to get it to work. But I was curious about this . This article [https://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/] is excellent for beginners.